# Do any Church Fathers speak about the similarity between εσωσεν and Ιησους?

Tags: church-fathers, greek, name-of-jesus, hebrew

The Greek verb for "he saves" is εσωσεν (*esosen*), and the Greek transliteration of the Hebrew name of Jesus (Yeshua, meaning Saviour, but coming from the Hebrew yoshia, meaning "He saves") is Ιησους (*iesous*).<sup>1</sup>

I'm certainly not privy to the internal minds of ancient Greek speakers, but I can imagine that if I were Greek-speaking, I would (if not consciously, then unconsciously) recognize the striking coincidence, and perhaps comment on it (it's my understanding that the Fathers in general understood the meaning of the Saviour's name to mean "Saviour").

### Question

Do any Fathers mention this similarity?

---

<sup>1 The only real different in pronunciation is the addition of "en" in the former (akin to the difference between "like" and "liken" in English, and the attendant unconscious recognition that the two are inherently related etymologically).</sup>

Comment: Is this question suitable for this site at all?

Comment: It just needs to be attached to a specific text. Up-voted pending an expected edit.

Comment: @Dottard A question about whether the Fathers taught a certain thing is literally the perfect example of a question about Christianity.